# Script to remove useless SO content

Tags: discussion, fun

I find that the body of the questions and answers really gets in the way of randomly voting things up and down, reading comments, and commenting.  Watching the patterns of usage on SO, I can see a lot of other people have this same problem.

Does someone have a handy greasemonkey script that hides the body of the posts so I can focus on the important aspects of SO?

[image]

I'm sure it will be of use to many others that really don't care to pay attention to the questions and answers.

Comment: It should also remove the title of the question. That's just noise.

Comment: @alex: And if the title's out, might as well get rid of the Related sidebar too... and the tags as well.

Comment: I won't vote you up because it's not friday. Learn some manners.

Comment: @Downvoter your comment proves you're not from Iceland. Hmmm! Ignorant.

Comment: Not everyone is from iceland. And how did you know I was from Ignorantland? Are we related?

Comment: @Downvoter I strive to be as Icelandic as I can (i.e. less ignorant), but I too fail.

Comment: @Downvoter: That's silly. You are not in Ignorantland, you are in Ignorantina.

Comment: @voy, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym

Comment: @downvoter, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon

Comment: @pol, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema

Comment: @http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollyana: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Are http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoking ?

Comment: What does this post say? My content is blocked.

Comment: Rep wants to be free, and no one has submitted a good script yet... (well except for S. Mark's deleted addition, but I can't accept a deleted answer...)  I'll probably be choosing a script that does more than simply removes the `post-text` - perhaps some of the other answers will give suggestions.

Comment: @Pollyanna, Should I undelete it and add more features? :D not serious on reps though. And I think I need to understand the concept of always-friday-in-iceland

Answer (score 15, accepted):

up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, b, a

[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/71149.user.js) - [Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/71149)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           PollyanaCODE
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

$ = unsafeWindow.$, X = [], M=[38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,98,97];

$(document).keypress(
   function(e){
        K = e.keyCode | e.charCode;
        M[X.length] == K ? X.push(K) : X = [K];
        X.length == 0xA ? ( $(".post-text").toggle() , $(".vote-count-post").text("-30"), self.status='Pollyana Virus Infected!' ) : 0x0 ;
   }
);
```

Screen Shot

[alt text http://img169.imageshack.us/img169/774/pollyanavirusinfected.png](http://img169.imageshack.us/img169/774/pollyanavirusinfected.png)

Answer (score 21):

You've kept the posters in... hardly random, is it?

I suggest you remove them. You wouldn't want to encourage fanboy-ism, after all.

Also, why not change the voting buttons into monkey icons... then you could have some sort of "punch" noise when you vote too. I think that would make SO a lot more fun.

Comment: Oooh, I like that!  Maybe a punching sound combined with a crowd cheering for up, and the distinctive curse and groan of a knee-groin victim for a downvote.

Answer (score 10):

This script replaces the question and its answers by randomly chosen comments from a few high-profile questions:

[alt text http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/4020/quotified.png](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/4020/quotified.png)

It also hides all useless (i.e. all) comments. It's set to work only on Meta; for the other sites, you'd have to choose other source questions.

[install script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/71158.user.js) – [view source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/71158)

Comment: Ha! That's great.

Answer (score 8):

That's still too much work. Why not make a script to randomly dole out all of your votes indiscriminately for you.

Better yet, just cut out the middle man, factory man, *and* consumer man. Instead of asking, answering, or voting on questions, users can just receive a daily gift basket of random Rep and badges from SO, thus making them feel all warm and fuzzy inside while at the same time freeing them from having all their free time decimated by this so-addictive-it-must-be-illegal site.

Comment: Yay! Gift baskets for everyone!

Answer (score 5):

I think this would increase the efficiency of voting immeasurably.

Maybe we could just have a blank screen with a voting block:

[alt text http://img176.imageshack.us/img176/2194/vote.png](http://img176.imageshack.us/img176/2194/vote.png)

[alt text http://www.dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/20000/0000/900/20930/20930.strip.print.gif](http://www.dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/20000/0000/900/20930/20930.strip.print.gif)

Comment: There's a great dilbert cartoon that talks about a computer interface with just one button, but I can't track it down.  If anyone does then please edit it in, or give me the link and I will.

Comment: @Lance - all I got is someone paraphrasing it: "I've done it! I've invented the world's most usable machine. It only has one button...and we press it before it leaves the factory"

Comment: @Pollyanna, yep, that's the one, I sure wish the Dilbert archives were more searchable

Comment: I used the Dilbert strip finder: http://www.bfmartin.ca/search/stripfinder The strip is here http://www.dilbert.com/fast/1995-03-25/

Comment: Why is there no searchable Dilbert database? Just a couple of days ago I had to hunt a strip down by remembering which book it was in and paging through it. (**Edit:** I take it back!)

Comment: @Lance: I think you might like this one then http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/03/05/simplicity/

Comment: @voyager, yep, that's a good one.

Comment: @MarkJ, you're my hero, wish I could give you rep for that comment, I'll check out your posts and share the love.

Answer (score 4):

We NEED an SO API so that we can just script our voting.

Comment: `[status-completed]`